# Is there any way to enforce enum types naming convention with Checkstyle?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, checkstyle

We want to enforce naming convention for enum types in our project to start with E letter (so enums should be named e.g. `EType`, `EColor` etc).

I see the way to enforce naming convention for interfaces and classes types (using "Class declaration" and "Interface declaration" tokens in [TypeName rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html)).

Is there a way to do this for enums?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no easy way to do this with checkstyle so you need to write your own check to do this.

See: [Extending Checkstyle - Writing checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no corresponding rule in the naming conventions set. But you could achieve the desired result using a [RegExp](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Regexp) check ([explanation](http://regex101.com/r/pU8aS9) of the regex):

```xml
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="format" value="\benum\s+\S\S(?&lt;!E[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/>
    <property name="message"
        value="Enums must start with a capital 'E', e.g. EMyEnum"/>
    <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

This ignores matches in comments (like when an enum declaration was commented out) and also works if there is a newline between the `enum` keyword and the identifier. Since `enum` is a keyword in Java, there should not be many false positives.

Comment: Seems promising, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is not. But you can define your own rule. See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now with the [TypeName rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#TypeName) mentioned by OP, using the `ENUM_DEF` token.

Something like this should work (based on the rule's example, not tested) :

```
<module name="TypeName">
    <property name="format" value="^E[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="ENUM_DEF"/>
</module>
```